# Several SSH keys and user accounts

Tags: windows, git, ssh, gitlab

I have two user accounts in Gitlab. One with `axmug` user and the other one with `GbFlow`.
When I log in using `axmug` user there is any key in the profile settings.
But when I log in using `GbFlow` user I created an SSH key file and I can watch it in the profile settings.
I use Git Bash on Windows 7 and when I type `cd /Users/Invitado/.ssh` and `ls`, I can watch three files: `id_rsa`, `id_rsa.pub` and `known_hosts`.
This key was generated using `axmug` user. Both users have different emails.

What I want to do is upload an Android project using `GbFlow` user. When I tried, I typed the following in Git Bash command line:

```
git init
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:GbFlow/GlobalFlow.git
git add .                                                           
git commit
git push -u origin master
```

Everything worked except the last line: `git push -u origin master`. At this point I displayed the error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have the keys created. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`Invitado` means those ssh keys are created with the `Guest` account.

If you are not logged on as a `Guest`, but with your actual account, ssh will look for those keys in `%HOME%\.ssh`, with `HOME` set by default to `%USERPROFILE%`.
Type `set us` to see the value of `USERPROFILE`.

> This key was generated using `axmug` user.

It does not matter with which *local* Windows account those keys were created. What matters is *where* the public `id_rsa.pub` was copied to: in which GitLab account. See "[How to create your SSH Keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-your-ssh-keys.html)"

That would be the first reason why GitLab does not authenticate you properly: move those keys in your own `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh` to benefit from `GbFLow` identity (Assuming `GbFlow` profile has the public key in his/her settings).
Type `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` to confirm you are seen as `GgFlow`.

---

If, from the same local Windows account (`Invitado` or otherwise) you need to manage two different GitLab remote accounts, then see [Working with non-default SSH key pair paths](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#working-with-non-default-ssh-key-pair-paths), and use a `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config` file.

```
# GbFlow
Host gbflow
Hostname gitlab.com
RSAAuthentication yes
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gbflow_rsa

# axmug
Host axmug
Hostname gitlab.com
RSAAuthentication yes
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/axmug_rsa
```

Then use the ssh url `bgflow:<user>/<repo.git>` or `axmug:<user>/<repo.git>`

This assume you have created two different sets of ssh pairs keys.

For `gbflow` (renaming the existing `id_rsa`/`id_rsa.pub` files):

```
~/.ssh/gbflow_rsa
~/.ssh/gbflow_rsa.pub
```

For `axmug` (with `ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -C "axmug GitLab access" -q -f ~/.ssh/axmug_rsa`):

```
~/.ssh/axmug_rsa
~/.ssh/axmug_rsa.pub
```

Comment: Thanks for answering VonC. After searching in internet I read the following post: https://coderwall.com/p/7smjkq/multiple-ssh-keys-for-different-accounts-on-github-or-gitlab. But I can't connect to the server when I ssh-add -D. The solution is to type eval `ssh-agent -s` and retry the command. When I retype it I have the same error: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent. How can I fix it?

Comment: No need for that unless you have created a private ssh key with passphrase.

Comment: I typed set us and I didn't watch anything. After typing ssh -T git@gitlab.com I watched Permission denied <Public Key>. I am stuck. I don't know what to do. I know I have to upload the project via https but I can't do it because when I typed git push -u origin master I watched the same error: Permission denied <Public Key>. What I must to do in order to upload my project? Thanks

Comment: @axmug First, go back to a CMD session (not a git bash session, where `set us` would not work). Second, generate 2 sets of keys, and register one for GbFlow and the other for axmug GitLab account, as described in  https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-your-ssh-keys.html. Finally, create the %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config file as I mention in the answer, and check that `ssh -T gbflow` and `ssh -T axmug` does work. And in your repo, do a `git set-url origin gbflow:GbFlow/GlobalFlow.git`. `git push` will then work.

Comment: Thanks for answering VonC. According what you told me in the last comment, I created the two keys for users axmug and GbFlow. The next step is to create the config file described in your answer, is that right? Ia am a little bit confused. Thanks

Comment: @axmug yes, but you need also to make sure the right public keys are registered, one for each account, on GitLab. (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-your-ssh-keys.html)

Comment: After creating the config file and type ssh -T gitlab.com it works. But What I don't understand is the next step: do in my repo git set-url origin gbflow:GbFlow/GlobalFlow.git. What does git set-url means? Thanks

Comment: @axmug it means that it (ie `git remote set-url`) replaces your current origin url (which is a full ssh url `git@gitlab.com:<user>/repo.git`) by one which is managed by  `~/.ssh/config`: `gbflow:GbFlow/GlobalFlow.git` (if you want to push as `gbflow` for instance, because that abbreviated url will use `gbflow` private ssh key, as specified in the `~/.ssh/config` file)

Comment: what you told me it doesn't work. I typed git remote  add morigin git@gitlab.com:GbFlow/GlobalFlow.git and it works. But after typing git push -u morigin master I watched the error: permission denied (public key). Fatal: could not read the remote repository. What's wrong? Thanks

Comment: @axmug I never mentioned `morigin`. Always `origin`. And I mentioned `git remote set-url origin gbflow:GbFlow/GlobalFlow.git`.

Comment: Yeah. What you mention works. But when I type git push -u origin master I watch the error: ssh: Could not resolve hostname gbflow: no address associated with name
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.. I am stuck.

Comment: @axmug check your HOME environment variable: ssh needs %HOME%\.ssh\config.

Comment: I checked the HOME environment variable typing set home but I didn't watch anything. How can I set it with %HOME%\.ssh\config value?

Comment: No problem: if HOME is not defined, then it defaults to USER PROFILE.

Comment: Thanks for all answers. I am watching the files uploaded. I fixed the problem typing git remote set-url origin gbflow.gitlab.com:GbFlow.gitlab.com/GlobalFlow.git and then git push -u origin master.

Comment: @axmug no: it is `gbflow.gitlab.com` only if you set `Host` to `gbflow.gitlab.com`: the value before the '`:`' is the `Host` in the `.ssh/config` file. Is your user named `GbFlow.gitlab.com`?

Comment: What I typed is git remote set-url origin gbflow.gitlab.com:GbFlow/GlobalFlow.git and gbflow.gitlab.com is the name of the server (Host in the config file).

Comment: So that is good. But what surprised me is the string after the :. You used GbFlow.gitlab.com: is that the name of the user on gitlab.com?

Comment: No. The username is Gbflow

Comment: Then why not user that in your url? gbflowgitlab.com:gbflow/Global flow.git.

Comment: Maybe it works, but the error was the server was not recognized, so I typed the name of Host in the config file.

Comment: "the error was the server was not recognized" : that is for the part *before* the `:`. The part of the url *after* the `:` is `<user>/<repo.git>`: so use the user account for that part.